# How to add a way to receive a score and return a string based on the score to a function?

Tags: python

Thanks for the answers. This code works fine for this.

```
def rate_score(selection):
    if selection < 1000:
        return "Nothing to be proud of!"

    elif selection >= 1000 and selection < 10000:
        return "Not bad."

    elif selection >= 10000:
        return "Nice!"

def main():
    print "Let's rate your score."
    while True:
        selection = int(raw_input('Please enter your score: '))
        break
    print 'You entered [ %s ] as your score' % selection
    score = rate_score(selection)
    print score

main()
```

However I also need to set the parameter of rate_score(selection) to 0 as the default and add a call to rate_score(selection) in which you pass no value to the function. I have revised the code to this:

```
def rate_score(selection):
    if selection < 1000:
        return "Nothing to be proud of!"

    elif selection >= 1000 and selection < 10000:
        return "Not bad."

    elif selection >= 10000:
        return "Nice!"

    else:
        selection = 0

selection = int(raw_input("Enter your score. "))

score = rate_score(selection)
print score
```

Did I at least set it up so that the default parameter would be 0? If not how should I go about changing it to be the default parameter of rate_score()? Also I do not know how to go about allowing no value to be passed to rate_score considering you get an error if you do not enter anything because of raw_input.

Comment: There is no question here. What are you supposed to be doing?

Comment: Sorry I edited the post. I'm just rushing all over the place with backed up homework.

Comment: Try replacing the word `print` with `return`.

Comment: I hope that whatever you learn about python is not *the only thing* you learn when you try to catch up on your homework.

Comment: Not to be rude, but have you looked up "python return a value" or anything of the like? It seems like you haven't tried much.

Comment: So you need to catch up with your homework... and the way you want to catch up is to ask some other guys to do it for you... that's not called "doing your homework", that's called "not facing your homework". Use google, read the python tutorials, make an effort to solve your problems by yourself.

Comment: Barranka I have used google. I have a textbook for python as well but it does not give you any details. It likes to show you that you can do things, but never tells you how. I have made an effort myself. I can see why you would think so, but without knowing the whole story please refrain from taking such a hostile comment towards me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lasse V. Karlsen commented on your question, you'll first need to replace your `print` with a `return`.

You probably want another condition if the score *is* something to be proud of, right?
Here's that, while receiving the score as input from the user:

```
def rate_score(selection):
    if selection < 1000:
        return "Nothing to be proud of!"
    else:
        return "Now that's something to be proud of!"

def main():
    print "# rate_score program #"
    while True:
        try:
            selection = int(raw_input('Please enter your score: '))
        except ValueError:
            print 'The value you entered does not appear to be a number !'
            continue
        print 'You entered [ %s ] as your score' % selection
        response = rate_score(selection) # Now the function rate_score returns the response
        print response # Now we can print the response rate_score() returned

main()
```

[`raw_input` is a Built-in Function in python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), which can be used to get input from a user. 
Using `raw_input()`, and [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), we can also make sure that the input from the user is a number. This is because `int()` will throw a specific error if you try to give it something that is not a number. [The error it throws is called a `ValueError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError).

```
>>> int('notanumber')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'notanumber'
```

By anticipating this error (`ValueError`), and then catching it with the `except` statement, we can inform a user when our program has determined that their input did not evaluate as a number. Note that in order to catch the error with the `except` statement, the expression which throws the error must be evaluated by the `try` statement, hence:

```
try:
    # begin code which we know will throw the `ValueError`
    selection = int(raw_input('Please enter your score: '))
except ValueError:
    # what to do if the `ValueError` occurs?
    # tell the user that what they entered doesn't appear to be a number
    print 'The value you entered does not appear to be a number !'
    continue
```

Answer (score 3):

*"and **return** a string"* - That's what the `return` keyword is for:

```
def rate_score(score):
    if score < 1000:
        return "Nothing to be proud of."
```